# When following ref I get to a cs file under AppData folder?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I got a old ASP.NET Webform website and this contains a couple of usercontrols and pages. I have now added a couple off properties to a usercontrol that I need to use from one of the where the control is used.

The problem is that I can´t find the new properties from within the page(on the control). The old properties is however there and if I try "Go to Defenition" I will end up in a file under AppData\Local\Temp.

I have tried to remove the tempfile but it will still not update with the new properties?

Why?

Comment: Is this a "Web Application" (pre-compiled) or "Web Site" (compiled on demand) type of project?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean but this is a regular ASP.NET 4.0 website that will run with the mini IIS(Visual Studio IIS) during debug.